# What controls the spin down of idle external hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I'd like to setup a spin down time for idle external hard drives. I have several candidate solution. In order to find the proper one I'd like to know what measures the idle time and starts the spin down process after the given period. Is it the HDD firmware, the chip of the external HDD case (USB3-SATA bridge) or the operating system, or maybe all of them in some combination? Please provide references to your answer, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both the harddisk itself and external sources can spin a disk down.
And in theory the USB to SATA bridge could be a third source.

---

You did not specify an OS, so lets focus on hdparm which is a very nice tool and is included in most BSD and Linux distributions. (And there is even a limited windows port of it).

From [the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man8/hdparm.8.html) (`man hdparm` on the command line):

> -S Set the standby (spindown) timeout for the drive. This value is used by the drive to determine how long to wait (with no disk activity) before turning off the spindle motor to save power.
>
> The encoding of the timeout value is somewhat peculiar. A value of zero means "timeouts are disabled": the device will not automatically enter standby mode. Values from 1 to 240 specify multiples of 5 seconds, yielding timeouts from 5 seconds to 20 minutes. Values from 241 to 251 specify from 1 to 11 units of 30 minutes, yielding timeouts from 30 minutes to 5.5 hours. A value of 252 signifies a timeout of 21 minutes. A value of 253 sets a vendor-defined timeout period between 8 and 12 hours, and the value 254 is reserved. 255 is interpreted as 21 minutes plus 15 seconds.

Note that some older drives may have very different interpretations of these values.

`dparm -I /dev/sda | grep level` will show the current spindown value, for example: `Advanced power management level: 254`

Comment: The question was theoretical, because I have another question with exact details. We are talking about a an Odroid XU4, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server, Captiva USB3-SATA bridge with asmedia ASM1053 chip, Western Digital blue HDD WD10EZEX 1TB. According to some 1-2 years old forums dparm idle spindown timing does not work with external USB drives and WD drives. I'll try it, maybe this problem was fixed. On the device I was not able to run the dparm command. I did not find it in the apt repos, what I found is hdparm. After installation the `hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep level` returns empty string.

Comment: Ohh btw. the other question is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/732099/idle-spin-down-time-of-external-hdd I don't think it qualifies as duplicate, because I asked different things. Ofc. the goal is the same.

Comment: Removing the disk and plugging it into a disktop and then configuring it wih hdparm should work (even if you then move it back to the original system). Assuming ofc. that the old system does not try to set its own values.

Comment: Should I configure it in the rack or plug it into sata directly? According to a Hungarian forum the spindown is controlled by the SATA-USB bridge, so if it does not support this feature, the operating system won't be able to spindown the disk using the bridge. Luckily the chip supports this feature. According to another forum it is possible to set idle spindown times directly on the HDD, which is interesting, because I thought, that the operating system controls this thing http://apmtimer.sourceforge.net/. That's why it is not clear how to solve this.

Comment: Setting it directly on the disk is what we try to do with hdparm. We tell the disk 'please use this profile'.  As for the bridge, it can also send the disk the same command. **can**.  Not sure if it does so. Only the manufacturer of that bridge knows how it is programmed.

Comment: According to this hdparm sets a different thing and it does not persist, while apm timer settings persist on the HDD: http://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=29531&start=20&mobile=mobile Complicated topic, even without using an usb bridge.

Comment: So if I set the thing on a desktop PC with hdparm, it won't have any effect, because after attaching the device to the server machine, it won't remember the settings. At least this sounds logical to me. I ask this on this hddguru forum, maybe they know a lot in this topic.

Comment: I found out that the HDD does not want to idle spin down only if the USB cable is unplugged or the server does not run. Otherwise I think Ubuntu spins it down after 10 minutes. Your answer certainly works by SATA drives. I am not sure about USB drives, but I think I can accept it.

Comment: standby timeout is NOT the same thing as APM